# Get Device Information from C# IntPtr

Tags: c#, raw-input

**Background/Disclaimer:**
Im currently working on a C# project that requires interaction with Microsoft's Raw Input API. I am a C# developer and I'm completely new to the Raw Input API 'space' and new to related APIs (i.e. Windows Forms, user32.dll, Windows Programming) in general.

**The Question:**
Due to my background, I prefer to use the Raw Input API through a C# managed wrapper library; I have chosen SharpDX, but I am open to other C# solutions. 
I've gotten raw input to work, capturing both the keyboard event and a IntPtr representing the keyboard device. Is there a way I can find more information on the device (such as Guid, Product Name, Device Name, etc) with this IntPtr reference?

**What has been done so far**

1. Got Raw Input to work via an EventHandler delegate and SharpDX API; got an IntPtr to the device.
2. For the past 3 days, scoured the internet using my mediocre searching skills; found no C# managed way (safe context) to get device information from a C# IntPtr.

**Note:** Though a code answer is helpful, I'm not here just to "grab-an-answer-and-run". As long as its possible to do this via some C# managed free library or without a C# 'unsafe' context; sending me links to the documentation of said library and to the library's main site with some general guidelines should suffice.

Comment: Welcome!  _"links to the documentation of said library and to the library's main site with some general guidelines should suffice"_ - Sadly, _[questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software **library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Where on SO should I ask a question that could have multiple, opinionated answers? That is; where can I ask a question where I am able to consider multiple, potentially viable solutions and choose one that meets requirements? For clarity, I've also added what I have done so far.

Comment: You're essentially asking for _"links"_ which is a tad naughty

Comment: What am I allowed to ask for then? A concept or pseudo-algorithm? If at any point someone feels that I'm not putting forth enough effort, then I'm "at peace" if they don't prefer to help (i.e. ignore my question). However, I feel that downvoting may hinder the ability for others who are willing to help me in the future; as enough downvotes will get me "booted".

Comment: @AMemberofDollars they are interpreting you are asking for links for a wrapper library or how to use one. But the way I understand it, you want to get the device info, given a pointer to the device, right? Is my answer incomplete or wrong?

Comment: @Enfyve Your answer is a good, helpful answer. I just wanted to see if anyone else has an acceptable answer as well. From my understanding, I cannot mark multiple answers as an accepted answer. If I could do this, I would. If after awhile, there doesn't seem to be any other possible, valid answers, then I'll be happy to mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Very valid, there are many ways to skin a cat. I'm not pushing to get my answer accepted, I just thought it might be lacking information since you hadn't made a comment on/about it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes, the pointer should be a reference to the handle of the input device, therefore you should be able to invoke [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the desired information.

You'll have to either import this external function call yourself [(from KMoussa's comment)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getrawinputdeviceinfo), or in your C# managed wrapper of choice.

Comment: P/Invoke for GetRawInputDeviceInfo http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getrawinputdeviceinfo

Comment: @KMoussa Thanks, I updated my answer to include your link. I always forget to use pinvoke.net

Comment: thanks - I probably should have edited your answer instead of adding a comment to be more clear, so thanks for doing the edit :)